How to mathematically model a lumped-mass cable model?
I am trying to simulate a 2D cable as a lumped-mass model. I think that it's like a chain of pendulums and I would preferably like to be damped. Just to make sure, this is the cable model that I'm trying.:

The blue dots have mass, but not the links. The segments cannot deform. How can I do it, please?
